# How to send emoticon in LINE message API

Tags: ruby, unicode, ruby-on-rails-5, utf-16, line-api

I tested emoticon in node.js in this way.

I do the same in my rails project but i was not able to send unicode like this. I don't know how to send emoticon in rails with LINE Message API.

```
messages.push(
           type: 'text',
           text: "\uDBC0\uDC84"
           )
```

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/line/line-bot-sdk-ruby

Comment: What character is it supposed to be?

Comment: I solved this problem. it was about the unicode and UTF-8 encoding. Thank you for your comments!